# Experimental invariance of average speed of light in any closed path

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames

Can we safely say that:

> Even without assuming Einstein's postulates, experiments have shown that measuring the average speed of light in the vacuum on a closed path always produces the same result: the constant c?

Do we need to specify that the measure must be performed in an inertial frame or possibly something else, or can we state this principle in general?

Comment: The reference frame doesn't matter when measuring the speed of light - it would always yield the same result!

Comment: @uriyabsc what about non-inertial reference frames?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the measure must be performed in an inertial frame. In a non-inertial frame the speed of light is $c$ only locally (if the paths are small enough); if the paths are large it may differ. For example, the speed of light in a rotating frame is different in the direction of rotation and against it; this is the Sagnac effect.